# Drawing blanks in a textbox

Tags: winforms, textbox

I would like display, in a textbox, the spaces and the carriage return in order to show the user the exact test formatting, ie using a central point for spaces and an arrow for CRLF. Any idea ?

Comment: Drawing on top of a textbox is hard. Very hard. So hard you really don't want to do it. See if the [`MaskedTextBox` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) won't work for you first.

Comment: MaskedTextBox does not fit my needing. Maybe I try to write one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eah, it's really hard! But you can replace spaces with some printable symblos for display purposes only. But carriage you shouldn't replace, just add new Symbols.
And before text usage, before writing to file for example, just convert all symbols back to spaces.
This solutiond of course, is not universal and complete.

Comment: This is a possibility, but I can't accept as an answer just because it is a workaround :)